# How do you say common tennis terms in French?

Tags: terminologie, sport

I design and develop a tennis scorekeeping app for Apple Watch, and would like to localize it for French.
[image]
This is my first experience with localization and would like to get it right without relying on something like Google Translate. Any thoughts on how the text in the screenshots would be said in French would be greatly appreciated (except for "Cancel" which is automatically localized). A few other terms I'd like to translate:

- Ad in
- Ad out
- Break point
- Set point
- Match point

Comment: Have you look at a dictionnary first?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you could look them up and ask for a validation instead? I'm pretty sure 80% of them can be found very easily.

Comment: That can be difficult because we use a mixture of French and English terms but this is my contribution: "Tiebreak sets" = "Jeux décisifs" ("jeu décisif" if singular); "Advantage" = "Avantage"; "Coin Toss" = "Pile ou face"; "You won..." = "Vous avez gagné le pile ou face. Qui servira en premier ?"; "Opponent" = "Votre adversaire"; "You" = "Vous"; "15" = "15" (yes I am an idiot ); "Match point" = "Balle de match" (literally "Match ball"); "Set point" = "Balle de set"

Comment: @Toto & Teleporting Goat: you are right BUT translating an interface is far more challenging than just looking at a dictionary. There are zillions of applications  translated with a dictionary and they all are a pain to use because it just does not make sense.

Comment: @SteffX I know! That's why I think it's a legit question, but it would have been recieved better if OP had done some of the work. I don't mind personally, but you'll get better answers if you show your research and where you're stuck.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat — I agree with you and that is why I didn't down vote your comment. The thing is that you can never know if the translation you found is even understandable, let alone accurate. I remember the Ghostbusters video game I bought a long time ago and the instructions said that "you should never move to the other side of a river"... but I have never found a river in that damn game. Until I realised that it was a bad translation of "you should never cross the streams"!!  That was a little bit different!

Comment: If you've ever seen the French Open, some of these can be easily picked up by even non-french speakers.

Comment: @SteffX Well, that and the fact that comments can't be downvoted :)

Comment: Your Apple Watch app looks so cool! Keeping the tennis score is a very good idea. Referee won't need a tablet anymore :) All the best.

Answer (score 2):

Français et joueur de tennis, voici ma contribution.

- Ad in= avantage service
- Ad out= avantage dehors ou avantage retour
- Tie break = jeu décisif, mais les joueurs emploient aussi beaucoup le terme tiebreak
- Set point, match point = balle de set, balle de match.
- surtout le terme deuce n'existe pas en francais, on dit 15A, 30A et 40A
- Best of 5 sets = au meilleur des 5 sets
- Coin toss = tirage au sort, mais le terme toss est aussi utilisé

Comment: "Deuce" se traduit par "égalité", dit lorsqu'il y a égalité après que les deux joueurs ont atteint le score de 40.

Comment: @Cedric J'ai ajouté un peu de formatage, hésite pas à modifier si ça te convient pas. Mais rappelle-toi qu'il faut deux retours à la ligne sinon ils ne sont pas pris en compte :) Aussi, les réponses sont acceptées aussi bien en anglais qu'en français, mais ici j'imagine que la personne qui a posé la question ne parle pas (ou pas bien) français et ne comprendra surement pas tes commentaires ^^

Comment: Tie break se dit habituellement *bris d’égalité* au Canada francophone. C’est régional, mais ça me semble néanmoins valoir la peine d’une indication.

Comment: Il me semble qu'on dit plus souvent « en trois sets gagnants » qu'« au meilleur des cinq sets ».

Comment: @jlliagre ...et il y a aussi ceux qui comme mes amis amateurs et moi disent *«en cinq sets»*, voire *«en cinq»*, ce qui, compte tenu des règles du tennis, nous indique assez clairement que la partie pourrait se terminer en trois. Une partie de cinq sets est une notion différente, cependant, pour laquelle les cinq sets durent être joués avant que n’émerge le vainqueur.